# Create csv file when certain size reached in c#

Tags: c#, csv, streamwriter

I have a method that writing a csv from list content. If the csv file size reach to specific size like 5MB, I want to create a new csv file so it won't grow too big if the list content is huge. Here is my code below but it is not working. I am getting error "file is being used by another process". Looks like this is not the correct way to create the new csv file.

```
    public static void WriteCSV<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string path)
    {
        Type itemType = typeof(T);
        var props = itemType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                            .OrderBy(p => p.Name);
        int filenumber = 0;
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", props.Select(p => p.Name)));

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", props.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null))));
                if (writer.BaseStream.Length > 5120)
                {
                    writer.Close();
                    writer.Dispose();
                    filenumber++;
                   var writer2 = new StreamWriter(string.Format(path, filenumber), false);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: That looks more like 5Kb than 5Mb.

Comment: Explicitly closing and disposing of a variable within its `using` statement is asking for trouble, I think.

Comment: @DStanley If I writer =  I have error "cannot assign to write because it is 'using variable'

Comment: at which line to you get the error?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Sorry I forgot it is supposed to be 5120 * 1024

Comment: This is one of those rare cases, then, where you may need to replace `using` with `try/finally`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is two-fold.

1. The method `string.Format(path, filenumber)` does not do what you expect it to. It actually expects a format string as the first argument like `"value goes here {0}"` and a variable to put into the place of the `{0}`. Since you give it only a path it will return simply the path, which is the same name as your previous file. Hence your get the error, because you are trying to access the same file again.

Solution to 1):

1.1) you need to break the path into the path and the filename,

1.2) then take the filename without extension,

1.3) then concatenate the number to the filename

1.4) reconstruct the path.

Problem 2)

The iteration over the collection should not be inside the using block of the writer. It even does not depend on the writer. This makes it impossible for you to use another writer without specifying a new instance each time. This would make the code ugly and unnecessarily complicated.

Remove the using block and dispose the writer by hand as you already do:
Here is an examplary programm that does the trick.

```
void Main()
{
    string path = @"C:\WorkSpace\temp\test\fileName.csv";


    List<string> items = Enumerable.Range(1, 1200).Select(x => $"Something: {x} else {x+2} ").ToList();

    int filenumber = 0;
    var writer = new StreamWriter(path);
    string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(path);


    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", item.Split(' ')));
        if (writer.BaseStream.Length > 120)
        {
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
            filenumber++;
            writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(pathOnly, $"{fileName}{filenumber}{extension}"), false);
        }
    }

    // don't forget to close and dispose the last instance of the writer
    writer.Close();
    writer.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I hard coded the path, but on the next loop I get the error "The process cannot access the file 'D:\Temp\output2.csv' because it is being used by another process"

Comment: @Frost ah I forgot, you need to close and dispose the last instance of the writer. I edited my answer.

Comment: I have performance problem when I process 20K records. Writing on the csv become slow when it reached 10K. Is there way to overcome this?

Comment: @Frost did you benchmark your code? try to find out which part makes it slow. you can use `System.Diagnostic.Stopwatch`

Comment: It is the writing to csv that causing the lowness. Although it is creating new file when it reached certain size, the old and new file are still using same thread.